# onMapClick does not work on the overlay map but works out of it's boundary

Tags: java, android, geojson

I am doing following in my activity which is pretty simple right? but the problem is: **onMapClick** does not invoke when I click over the area where the overlay has been drawn, out of this area works just fine.

```
drawOverlay();    
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                //do my stuff here
                Toast.makeText(this, "HelloWorld", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you creating a GroundOverlay?

Comment: I am drawing heatmap overlay.

Comment: as far as I know there are no click listeners to detect when a user touches a heatmap tileoverlay.